Javascript Error: require is not defined is the Jupyter Notebook Macbook Pro OS
I'm encountering a JavaScript error, "require is not defined", when trying to run Jupyter Notebook on a MacBook Pro. This issue occurs in both Edge and Chrome browsers. Below is the JavaScript snippet causing the issue:I've attempted basic troubleshooting such as clearing the browser cache and ensuring my browser is up-to-date, but the error persists. How can I resolve this issue to properly use JavaScript functionalities within my Jupyter Notebook?
# Prepping the json file
holiday_json = {
"name": "flare",
"children": [
{
"name": "Additional",
"children":[
{"name": "Batalla de Pichincha",       "size": 5.0},
{"name": "Cantonizacion de Cayambe",   "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Cantonizacion de El Carmen", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Cantonizacion de Guaranda",  "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Cantonizacion de Latacunga", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Cantonizacion de Libertad",  "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Cantonizacion de Quevedo",   "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Cantonizacion de Riobamba",  "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Cantonizacion de Salinas",   "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Cantonizacion del Puyo",     "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Carnaval",                   "size": 0.0},
{"name": "Dia de Difuntos",            "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Dia de la Madre",            "size": 5.0},
{"name": "Dia de la Madre-1",          "size": 5.0},
{"name": "Dia del Trabajo",             "size": 5.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Guayaquil",    "size": 5.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Guayaquil-1",  "size": 5.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Quito",        "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Quito-1",      "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Navidad+1                                      ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Navidad-1                                      ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Navidad-2                                      ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Navidad-3                                      ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Navidad-4                                      ", "size": 6.0},
]
},
{
"name":  "Holiday",
"children":[
{"name": "Fundacion de Ambato",       "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Cuenca",       "size": 7.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Esmeraldas",   "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Ibarra",       "size": 7.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Loja",         "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Machala",      "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Manta",        "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Riobamba",     "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Santo Domingo", "size": 6.0}
]
},
{
"name": "Event",
"children": [
{"name": "Inauguracion Mundial de futbol Brasil          ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Independencia de Ambato                        ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Independencia de Cuenca                        ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Independencia de Guaranda                      ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Independencia de Guayaquil                     ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Independencia de Latacunga                     ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Mundial de futbol Brasil: Cuartos de Final     ", "size": 2.0},
{"name": "Mundial de futbol Brasil: Ecuador-Francia      ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Mundial de futbol Brasil: Ecuador-Honduras     ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Mundial de futbol Brasil: Ecuador-Suiza        ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Mundial de futbol Brasil: Final                ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Mundial de futbol Brasil: Octavos de Final     ", "size": 4.0},
{"name": "Mundial de futbol Brasil: Semifinales          ", "size": 2.0},
{"name": "Mundial de futbol Brasil: Tercer y cuarto lugar", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Navidad                                        ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Primer Grito de Independencia                  ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Primer dia del ano                             ", "size": 5.0},
{"name": "Primer dia del ano-1                           ", "size": 5.0},
{"name": "Black Friday",               "size": 3.0},
{"name": "Cyber Monday",               "size": 3.0},
{"name": "Provincializacion Santa Elena                  ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Provincializacion de Cotopaxi                  ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Provincializacion de Imbabura                  ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Provincializacion de Santo Domingo             ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi                               ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+1                             ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+10                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+11                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+12                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+13                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+14                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+15                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+16                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+17                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+18                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+19                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+2                             ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+20                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+21                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+22                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+23                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+24                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+25                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+26                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+27                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+28                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+29                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+3                             ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+30                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+4                             ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+5                             ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+6                             ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+7                             ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+8                             ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+9                             ", "size": 1.0}
]
},
{
"name": "Transfer",
"children":[
{"name": "Traslado Batalla de Pichincha         ", "size": 2.0},
{"name": "Traslado Fundacion de Guayaquil       ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Traslado Fundacion de Quito           ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Traslado Independencia de Guayaquil   ", "size": 3.0},
{"name": "Traslado Primer Grito de Independencia", "size": 2.0},
{"name": "Traslado Primer dia del ano           ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Viernes Santo                         ", "size": 5.0}
]
},
    {
"name": "Bridge",
"children":[
{"name": "Puente Dia de Difuntos                         ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Puente Navidad                                 ", "size": 2.0},
{"name": "Puente Primer dia del ano                      ", "size": 2.0},
]
},
{
"name": "Work Day",
"children":[
    {"name": "Recupero puente Navidad", "size": 2.0},
    {"name": "ecupero puente primer dia del ano", "size": 2.0},
    {"name": "Recupero Puente Navidad", "size": 2.0},
    {"name": "Recupero Puente Primer dia del ano", "size": 2.0},
    {"name": "Recupero Puente Dia de Difuntos", "size": 2.0}
]
}
] 
}                          
# dumping the holiday_events data into a json file
with open('output.json', 'w') as outfile:  
    json.dump(holiday_json, outfile)
pd.read_json('output.json').head()

#Embedding the html string
html_string = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node:hover {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node--leaf {
  fill: white;
}

.label {
  font: 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff;
}

.label,
.node--root,
.node--leaf {
  pointer-events: none;
}

</style>
<svg width="760" height="760"></svg>
"""
# Finally embed the D3.js to produce the circular treemap
js_string="""
 require.config({
    paths: {
        d3: "https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min"
     }
 });

  require(["d3"], function(d3) {

   console.log(d3);

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = 20,
    diameter = +svg.attr("width"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

var color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateViridis)
    .domain([-4, 4]);

var pack = d3.pack()
    .size([diameter - margin, diameter - margin])
    .padding(2);

d3.json("output.json", function(error, root) {
  if (error) throw error;

  root = d3.hierarchy(root)
      .sum(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });

  var focus = root,
      nodes = pack(root).descendants(),
      view;

  var circle = g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null; })
      .on("click", function(d) { if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); });

  var text = g.selectAll("text")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
      .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

  var node = g.selectAll("circle,text");

  svg
      .style("background", color(-1))
      .on("click", function() { zoom(root); });

  zoomTo([root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + margin]);

  function zoom(d) {
    var focus0 = focus; focus = d;

    var transition = d3.transition()
        .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
        .tween("zoom", function(d) {
          var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [focus.x, focus.y, focus.r * 2 + margin]);
          return function(t) { zoomTo(i(t)); };
        });

    transition.selectAll("text")
      .filter(function(d) { return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline"; })
        .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0; })
        .on("start", function(d) { if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline"; })
        .on("end", function(d) { if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none"; });
  }

  function zoomTo(v) {
    var k = diameter / v[2]; view = v;
    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")"; });
    circle.attr("r", function(d) { return d.r * k; });
  }
});
  });
 """
h = display(HTML(html_string))
j = IPython.display.Javascript(js_string)
IPython.display.display_javascript(j)


What specific version of Jupyter Notebook? If it is above 7, you want the solutions that work in JupyterLab because Jupyter Notebook 7+ is built on same components as JupyterLab now. I see you have d3.js as a topic category here, and https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min is wrapped by require.config() and so I suspect you are actually looking to use D3.js? See here for more context, which leads to here.

 There's also this post for more insight.

The issue was resolved for me after installing the 'plotly' package, which is an interactive javascript-based visualization library for python

Assuming Jupyter Notebook 7+...
Work in progress:
Tried converting your D3.js-related code to what works with current JupyterLab and Jupyter Notebook 7+.
What is below seems to get past the current issue; however, whatever it is supposed to show doesn't show up in output area YET....
First cell content:
%%javascript
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.9.0/d3.min.js';
    document.head.appendChild(script);
    console.log(window.d3)

d3.min.js library updated URL was based on https://cdnjs.com/libraries/d3 . Tried. And tried with example like in SO, too.
Second cell content:
import json
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import Javascript, HTML
# Prepping the json file
holiday_json = {
"name": "flare",
"children": [
{
"name": "Additional",
"children":[
{"name": "Batalla de Pichincha",       "size": 5.0},
{"name": "Cantonizacion de Cayambe",   "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Cantonizacion de El Carmen", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Cantonizacion de Guaranda",  "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Cantonizacion de Latacunga", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Cantonizacion de Libertad",  "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Cantonizacion de Quevedo",   "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Cantonizacion de Riobamba",  "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Cantonizacion de Salinas",   "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Cantonizacion del Puyo",     "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Carnaval",                   "size": 0.0},
{"name": "Dia de Difuntos",            "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Dia de la Madre",            "size": 5.0},
{"name": "Dia de la Madre-1",          "size": 5.0},
{"name": "Dia del Trabajo",             "size": 5.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Guayaquil",    "size": 5.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Guayaquil-1",  "size": 5.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Quito",        "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Quito-1",      "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Navidad+1                                      ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Navidad-1                                      ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Navidad-2                                      ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Navidad-3                                      ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Navidad-4                                      ", "size": 6.0},
]
},
{
"name":  "Holiday",
"children":[
{"name": "Fundacion de Ambato",       "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Cuenca",       "size": 7.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Esmeraldas",   "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Ibarra",       "size": 7.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Loja",         "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Machala",      "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Manta",        "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Riobamba",     "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Fundacion de Santo Domingo", "size": 6.0}
]
},
{
"name": "Event",
"children": [
{"name": "Inauguracion Mundial de futbol Brasil          ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Independencia de Ambato                        ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Independencia de Cuenca                        ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Independencia de Guaranda                      ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Independencia de Guayaquil                     ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Independencia de Latacunga                     ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Mundial de futbol Brasil: Cuartos de Final     ", "size": 2.0},
{"name": "Mundial de futbol Brasil: Ecuador-Francia      ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Mundial de futbol Brasil: Ecuador-Honduras     ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Mundial de futbol Brasil: Ecuador-Suiza        ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Mundial de futbol Brasil: Final                ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Mundial de futbol Brasil: Octavos de Final     ", "size": 4.0},
{"name": "Mundial de futbol Brasil: Semifinales          ", "size": 2.0},
{"name": "Mundial de futbol Brasil: Tercer y cuarto lugar", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Navidad                                        ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Primer Grito de Independencia                  ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Primer dia del ano                             ", "size": 5.0},
{"name": "Primer dia del ano-1                           ", "size": 5.0},
{"name": "Black Friday",               "size": 3.0},
{"name": "Cyber Monday",               "size": 3.0},
{"name": "Provincializacion Santa Elena                  ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Provincializacion de Cotopaxi                  ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Provincializacion de Imbabura                  ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Provincializacion de Santo Domingo             ", "size": 6.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi                               ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+1                             ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+10                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+11                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+12                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+13                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+14                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+15                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+16                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+17                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+18                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+19                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+2                             ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+20                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+21                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+22                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+23                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+24                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+25                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+26                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+27                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+28                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+29                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+3                             ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+30                            ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+4                             ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+5                             ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+6                             ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+7                             ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+8                             ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Terremoto Manabi+9                             ", "size": 1.0}
]
},
{
"name": "Transfer",
"children":[
{"name": "Traslado Batalla de Pichincha         ", "size": 2.0},
{"name": "Traslado Fundacion de Guayaquil       ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Traslado Fundacion de Quito           ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Traslado Independencia de Guayaquil   ", "size": 3.0},
{"name": "Traslado Primer Grito de Independencia", "size": 2.0},
{"name": "Traslado Primer dia del ano           ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Viernes Santo                         ", "size": 5.0}
]
},
    {
"name": "Bridge",
"children":[
{"name": "Puente Dia de Difuntos                         ", "size": 1.0},
{"name": "Puente Navidad                                 ", "size": 2.0},
{"name": "Puente Primer dia del ano                      ", "size": 2.0},
]
},
{
"name": "Work Day",
"children":[
    {"name": "Recupero puente Navidad", "size": 2.0},
    {"name": "ecupero puente primer dia del ano", "size": 2.0},
    {"name": "Recupero Puente Navidad", "size": 2.0},
    {"name": "Recupero Puente Primer dia del ano", "size": 2.0},
    {"name": "Recupero Puente Dia de Difuntos", "size": 2.0}
]
}
] 
}                          
# dumping the holiday_events data into a json file
with open('output.json', 'w') as outfile:  
    json.dump(holiday_json, outfile)
pd.read_json('output.json').head()

#Embedding the html string
html_string = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node:hover {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node--leaf {
  fill: white;
}

.label {
  font: 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff;
}

.label,
.node--root,
.node--leaf {
  pointer-events: none;
}

</style>
<svg width="760" height="760"></svg>
"""
# Finally embed the D3.js to produce the circular treemap
js_string="""
var svg = d3.select(element)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 300);    
var diameter = +svg.attr("width"),
    margin = 20,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");
    
var color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateViridis)
    .domain([-4, 4]);

var pack = d3.pack()
    .size([diameter - margin, diameter - margin])
    .padding(2);

d3.json("output.json", function(error, root) {
  if (error) throw error;

  root = d3.hierarchy(root)
      .sum(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });

  var focus = root,
      nodes = pack(root).descendants(),
      view;

  var circle = g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null; })
      .on("click", function(d) { if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); });

  var text = g.selectAll("text")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
      .style("display", function(d) { return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

  var node = g.selectAll("circle,text");

  svg
      .style("background", color(-1))
      .on("click", function() { zoom(root); });

  zoomTo([root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + margin]);

  function zoom(d) {
    var focus0 = focus; focus = d;

    var transition = d3.transition()
        .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
        .tween("zoom", function(d) {
          var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [focus.x, focus.y, focus.r * 2 + margin]);
          return function(t) { zoomTo(i(t)); };
        });

    transition.selectAll("text")
      .filter(function(d) { return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline"; })
        .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0; })
        .on("start", function(d) { if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline"; })
        .on("end", function(d) { if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none"; });
  }

  function zoomTo(v) {
    var k = diameter / v[2]; view = v;
    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")"; });
    circle.attr("r", function(d) { return d.r * k; });
  }
});
 """
#h = display(HTML(html_string))

Third cell content:
Javascript(js_string)

Just shows blank area for now. Although something is there, or the space for it is made, because running that last cell produces space in the output area before next cell.
I'm not sure what is missing or not adapted well. However, the code on which it is based was much simpler, and so I could have definitely missed converting something.
